# InstallAnywhere 2018 issues on Windows 10

Tags: java, windows-10, installanywhere

I'm trying to install the product InstallAnywhere2018 on Windows 10 and after several attempts including compatibility modes, running as admin and checking my system path for the Java variables I still get the same error:

[image]

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.awt.image.DataBufferInt.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.image.Raster.createPackedRaster(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.image.DirectColorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.windows.TranslucentWindowPainter$BIWindowPainter.getBackBuffer(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.windows.TranslucentWindowPainter.updateWindow(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.windows.WWindowPeer.updateWindow(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.windows.WWindowPeer.show(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.setVisible(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.show(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.show(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.show(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Unknown Source)
at Flexeraat0.setVisible(Unknown Source)
at Flexeraat0.aj(Unknown Source)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgr.a0(Unknown Source)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgr.ac(Unknown Source)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgrBase.runPreInstall(Unknown Source)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgr.runPreInstall(Unknown Source)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.b0(Unknown Source)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.a5(Unknown Source)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.executeApplication(Unknown Source)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.Main.main(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.zerog.lax.LAX.launch(Unknown Source)
at com.zerog.lax.LAX.main(Unknown Source)
```

Any ideas of how to solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: The irony......

Answer (score 1):

Once it crashes you need to find `ISTPv2Setup.lax` file in your `C:\Users\[your_username]\AppData\Local\Temp\I[a_lot_of_numbers_here]\Windows`. And replace the last line in the ISTPv2Setup.lax file being this:

```
lax.nl.java.option.additional=
```

with this:

```
lax.nl.java.option.additional=-Xms1g -Xmx2g
```

This also works when getting a stack trace like this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.zerog.ia.installer.AAMgr.initAAMgr(Unknown Source)
    at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.a6(Unknown Source)
    at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.executeApplication(Unknown Source)
    at com.zerog.ia.installer.Main.main(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.zerog.lax.LAX.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.zerog.lax.LAX.main(Unknown Source)
```

The real exception is in `C:\Users\[your_username]\AppData\Local\Temp\lax-[a_lot_of_numers]-err.tmp`.

Answer (score -1):

Setup JAVA_OPTS as a system variable with the following content, the heap size you want. Java should be able to find it and act accordingly :

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1G -Xmx2G"
```

After that in a command prompt run the following commands:

```
SET JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1G -Xmx2G"
```

This can be explained as follows:

- allocate at minimum 1GBs of heap
- allocate at maximum 2GBs of heap

Comment: Let me give that a try.

Comment: I just tried it @mebin-joe and got the same error. Perhaps you have another idea? Thanks tho.

Comment: @Jean what is the version of Java you use ?

Comment: I have installed java version "1.8.0_202".